# Delete Hyper-V checkpoint from Hyper-V manager, but still have checkpoint backup file. Able to revert?

Tags: hyper-v

because I am trying to create the Hyper-V snapshot weekly automatically and will backup the checkpoint file to external HDD and then remove the checkpoint older than 7days. And I am wandering what if I delete Hyper-V checkpoint from Hyper-V manager, but still have to checkpoint backup file (like**.vmcx**,.**vmgs** and **.vmrs** file), am I able to revert it back using those backup file?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkpoints aren't backups. Stop doing this and implement a real backup solution. If nothing else, use Windows Server Backup. It's free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't backup the checkpoint file and recover from that state.

However, you can export the checkpoint with [Export-VMCheckpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/export-vmsnapshot?view=win10-ps), in fact, this command will bundle the VM with the checkpoint, so you'll be able to restore the VM when needed.

But, if you really want to use that as a backup, you must use ["Production checkpoints"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints) to leverage VSS in the host VM and create consistent backup.

Some details about exporting checkpoints here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints#exporting-checkpoints

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will read the link that you provided.